# how to put a div on a replace in javascript

Tags: javascript

HTML

```
    <body onload='load();' style="background:black;">
    <div class="container-cron stopwatch theme-1" id="stopwatch-1">
        <div class="the-time box-topo" id="disp" type="text"></div>
        <div class="start-stop" onclick="ss()">start</div>
        <div class="box-dir reset" onclick="r()">reset</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
        // 0/1 = start/end
        // 2 = state
        // 3 = length, ms
        // 4 = timer
        // 5 = epoch
        // 6 = disp el
        // 7 = lap count

        var t=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1];

        function ss() {
            t[t[2]]=(new Date()).valueOf();
            t[2]=1-t[2];

            if (0==t[2]) {
                clearInterval(t[4]);
                t[3]+=t[1]-t[0];
                /*document.getElementById('lap').innerHTML+=
                    '<tr><td>'+(t[7]++)+'</td><td>'+
                    format(t[1]-t[0])+'</td><td>'+
                    format(t[3])+'</td></tr>';*/
                t[4]=t[1]=t[0]=0;
                disp();
            } else {
                t[4]=setInterval(disp, 43);
            }
        }
        function r() {
            if (t[2]) ss();
            t[4]=t[3]=t[2]=t[1]=t[0]=0;
            disp();
            //document.getElementById('lap').innerHTML='';
            t[7]=1;
        }

        function disp() {
            if (t[2]) t[1]=(new Date()).valueOf();
            t[6].value=format(t[3]+t[1]-t[0]);
            var este = t[6].value=format(t[3]+t[1]-t[0]);
            document.title = este + " - O Cronometro";
            var tempo = document.getElementById('disp').value;
            var tempo = $('#disp').text(tempo);
        }
```

// *** The function *** here is the REPLACE***

```
        function format(ms) {
            var d=new Date(ms+t[5]).toString()
                //.replace(/.*(<div>[0-9][0-9]<\/div>:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]).*/, '$1');
                .replace(/.*([0-9][0-9]):([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]).*/, '<div>$1</div>, <div>$2</div>'); 
                //.replace(/.*([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]).*/, '$1');
            var x=String(ms%1000);
            while (x.length<3) x='0'+x;
            d+='.'+x;
            return d;
        }

        function load() {
            t[5]=new Date(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).valueOf();
            t[6]=document.getElementById('disp');

            //disp();

            if (!window.opener && window==window.top) {
                document.getElementById('remote').style.visibility='visible';
            }
        }

        function remote() {
            window.open(
                document.location, '_blank', 'width=800,height=350'
            );
            return false;
        }
```

Example:

```
.replace(/.*("open div tag"[0-9][0-9]"close div tag":[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]).*/, '$1');
```

**The function thus is showing the div tag for the User but I do not want this tag appears onscreen.**

thank you!

Comment: Should we decode the question?

Comment: how is anyone supposed to be able to interpret such limited information for a somewhat complex operation?

Comment: What are you even asking? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that your problem is with escaping the `/` in your closing `</div>`.

```
.replace(/.*(<div>[0-9][0-9]<\/div>:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]).*/, '$1')
```

UPDATE: Split a time in two `div`, one for the hour and the other one with the minutes and seconds.

```
.replace(/.*([0-9][0-9]):([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]).*/, '<div>$1</div><div>$2</div>');
```

UPDATE: If you want the `div` to be interpreted as a new element instead of text you have to add it as `innerHTML`:

```
    function disp() {
        if (t[2]) t[1]=(new Date()).valueOf();
        t[6].innerHTML=format(t[3]+t[1]-t[0]);
        var este = format(t[3]+t[1]-t[0]);
        document.title = este + " - O Cronometro";
    }
```

Comment: did not work. My full code is:

var d=new Date(ms+t[5]).toString()
.replace(/.*(<div>[0-9][0-9]<\/div>:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]).*/, '$1');

Comment: See the update. If I'm not wrong what you want is to wrap the hh:mm:ss between `div`?

Comment: yes, but with different div's.

Example:
<div>hh</div><div>mm:ss</div>

Comment: I tried in many ways but this appeared to <div> tag on the page, and not as html.

Comment: I need more context. Could you elaborate a little bit more what you are trying to achieve? Could you edit your question with the code that is using the `var d=new Date(ms+t[5]).toString().replace` statement? For example, posting the code you are trying to make it work.

Comment: The `format` function shows nothing on screen. It has to be in another part of your code that prints on screen, likely where this function is called.

Comment: now posted the entire file! see if it helps you understand.

Comment: Wow... Your code is a little bit... let's say cryptic. What HTML element is the one with `disp` id? Is it an `input`? Could you post the HTML code too, or at least the part with the `disp` one.

Comment: I think the issue is in your `disp` function. You have to append the formatted data as HTML.